# Broadcasting (Sharing) an array in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to share an array of characters among processes in MPI using MPI_Bcast(). Can anyone please let me know what must be passed as count and datatype in this case?

Array:

```
char * Var;
```

Broadcast function in MPI:

```
int MPI_Bcast( void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, MPI_Comm comm )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the MPI_Datatype `MPI_BYTE` and `int count` should be `strlen(Var) + 1`

**Here is the explanation why:**
For the datatype you need something that resembles a `char` much like you would send `MPI_INT` to transport integer arrays. This is what `MPI_BYTE` is for:

> MPI_BYTE:
>         This is an 8-bit positive integer betwee 0 and 255, i.e., a byte.

As for the length, that would have to be the size of the array. If I understand you correctly, this could vary depending on the length of the string you are sending. You therefore have to get the length of the string first by calling `strlen(Var)`. As

> The  strlen() function calculates the length of the string s,
>   excluding the terminating null byte ('\0').

You have to add one byte for the null character terminator of the string.

**Problem: The above code likely leads to memory leaks:** Your problem is, that it lies in the nature of `MPI_Broadcast` that only one of the participating processes is aware of the message being transmitted. Therefore only this process is able to determine the correct `count` all other processes are at loss as they have nothing to call `strlen` on. So what can we do about this?

1. broadcast the length of the string determined by the root processor via `strlen` first and then broadcast the actual string
2. use `MPI_Send` in combination with `MPI_Recv` allowing you to poll for the message size on the receiving proceses.

I would suggest using the second alternative as this avoids unnecessary barriers. A good how-to on this topic can be found [here](http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-send-and-receive/).