# broadcasting structs without knowing attributes

Tags: mpi, broadcast

I'm trying to use `MPI_Bcast` to share an instance of [cudaIpcMemHandler_t](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaIpcMemHandle__t.html#structcudaIpcMemHandle__t), but I cannot figure out how to create the corresponding `MPI_Datatype` needed for Bcast. I do not know the underlying structure of the cuda type, hence methods like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618937/trouble-understanding-mpi-type-create-struct) don't seem to work.  Am I missing something ?

Comment: as long as you are careful, it should be possible to send it as a C-style `char` or `unsigned char` array.  You can get the size of the datatype easily enough. That type is intentionally "opaque".  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187427/broadcasting-sharing-an-array-in-mpi)

Comment: thanks! I think I got something working ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872764/broadcasting-structs-without-knowing-attributes#comment130440556_73872764) , I have a solution that seems to work, though its only been tested in a [toy program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73871402/multiple-processes-sharing-reading-from-one-large-block-of-cuda-device-memory):

```cpp
//  Broadcast the memory handle

    cudaIpcMemHandler_t  memHandler[1];
    if (rank==0){
        // set the handler content, e.g. call cudpaIpcGetMemHandle
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    // share the size of the handler with other objects
    int hand_size[1];
    if (rank==0)
        hand_size[0]= sizeof(memHand[0]);
    MPI_Bcast(&hand_size[0], 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // broadcase the handler as byte array
    char memHand_C[hand_size[0]];
    if (rank==0)
        memcpy(&memHand_C, &memHand[0], hand_size[0]);
    MPI_Bcast(&memHand_C, hand_size[0], MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank >0)
        memcpy(&memHand[0], &memHand_C, hand_size[0]);
```